# Send email directly from HTML form, without "mailto:"

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I have been looking around here to find an answer to my question. 
I have implemented a html form in my index.html.

```
    <div id="contact" name="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h2 class="centered">Support</h2>
          <hr class="red">
          <p>For more info and support, contact us</p>
          </div>
          <div class="centered"> <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 centered">

            <form action="send_form_email.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="contact" method="post" class="form" role="form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
                </div>
              </div>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                  <button class="btn btn btn-lg" type="submit">SEND</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <!-- form --> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- row --> 

      </div>

</div>
```

How can my readers send an email directly through the form without using "mailto" 
From what i have read i have to use a .php document also. I have tried this one:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

But it only takes me to a blank page.. domain.com/send_form_email.php

What changes need to be done on the .php page in order to complete it? As you probably understand a programmer made the html page, but he went incognito.

Sorry about my english skills.

Comment: Blank page => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and this `enctype="text/plain"` that needs to be removed and you've no input for `last_name`

Comment: I have no input for neither last_name or telephone, i've tried to remove that from the .php file, but it spawns back